# pyModbusTCP PC to PC connection

Tags: python, modbus-tcp, pymodbustcp

I'm trying to connect two pcs together using pyModbusTCP. When I run both the client and server locally using local host it works just fine.

When I try and run them on separate PC's the client takes a while to "connect" and then just reads the registers as "None". I have set a static IP address for the server as 192.254.100.101 and can ping it using terminal on the other PC. I also have a static IP address on the client side of 192.254.100.102.

Client Code:

```
    from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
    import time
    
    client = ModbusClient(host="192.254.100.101", port=502, debug = True)
    
    print("Opening client")
    client.open()
    print("Client open")
    try:
    
        while True:
    
            value = client.read_holding_registers(0)
            print(f"Register 0: {value}")
    
            time.sleep(1)
    
    
    except:
    
        print("Shutdown")
```

Server code:

```
    from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer, DataBank
    import time
    
    server =  ModbusServer(host= "192.254.100.101", port = 502, no_block=True)
    server.start()
    try: 
        print("Starting server...")
        server.start()
        print("Server is online")
        val = [0]
        while True:
            val0 = input("Val: ")
            val = [int(val0)]
            print(val)
            DataBank.set_words(0, val)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    
    except:
        print("Shutdown server")
        server.stop()
```

Comment: Most likely cause is a firewall running on the server ([`connect`](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.client.html#pymodbus.client.sync.ModbusTcpClient) returns `false` if the connection was unsuccessful). [Enabling logging](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/modbus_logging.html) might make testing easier.

Comment: @Brits, This package is not the same as pymodbus.

Comment: As @aniranmohammadpour says this is pyModbusTCP; however the advice still stands, just with different links - check the return value from [`client.open`](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/class_ModbusClient.html#pyModbusTCP.client.ModbusClient.open) and [enable logging](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/server.html). Currently there is insufficient information to say more.

Answer (score -1):

.i.e:

you have a Raspberry pi with the static IP address of "192.254.100.101" and some devices are connected to it, then when you send a request to it you will declare the slave id number too, here you requested a data register.

now in the server app, you will return the answer using the sender packet IP address.

Use Wireshark and your local network for understanding.

**Codes in java language Using [Modbus4J](https://github.com/MangoAutomation/modbus4j):**

```
public class MasterTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//        String host = "localhost";
          String host = "192.168.1.105";
//        String host = "YOUR-DEVICE-IP-THAT-IS-CONNECTED-TO-NETWORK";

        IpParameters ipParameters = new IpParameters();

        ipParameters.setHost(host);
        ipParameters.setPort(502);
        ipParameters.setEncapsulated(false);

        ModbusFactory modbusFactory = new ModbusFactory();



       //TcpMaster extends ModbusMaster + Creates an object with ipParameters in it
        ModbusMaster master = modbusFactory.createTcpMaster(ipParameters, true);
//        ModbusMaster master = modbusFactory.createTcpMaster(ipParameters, false);
        master.setTimeout(8000);
        master.setRetries(0);
        // openConnection method will be called - if KeepAlive be true - openConnection is in TcpMaster
        // openConnection method will close other connections
        // Socket.connect(ipParameters.getHost(), ipParameters.getPort(),getTimeout()) is in openConnection method
        master.init();

        try {
//          master.send(new WriteCoilRequest(3, 120, true));
//          master.send(new WriteCoilRequest(3, 256, false));
            master.send(new ReadCoilsRequest(1, 17, 1));
            master.send(new ReadCoilsRequest(3, 256, 1));



 master.send(new WriteRegisterRequest(2, 15, 5));
    ReadHoldingRegistersResponse rresponse = (ReadHoldingRegistersResponse) master
            .send(new ReadHoldingRegistersRequest(1, 15, 1));
    System.out.println(rresponse);

//            System.out.println(master.testSlaveNode(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    master.destroy();

}
}
```

**Slave codes in Java using Modbus4J:**

```
public class SlaveTest {

static Random random = new Random();
static float ir1Value = -100;

//TEST VALUES
private static Integer twoByteIntUnsignedSwapped = 29187; //Register 16
private static Integer twoByteIntSignedSwapped = -257; //Register 17
private static Long fourByteIntUnsignedSwappedSwapped = 16777216L; //Register 18
private static Long fourByteIntSignedSwappedSwapped = (long) -16777217; //Register 20
private static Long register22 = 2369850368L; ////Register 22


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ModbusFactory modbusFactory = new ModbusFactory();
    ModbusSlaveSet slave = modbusFactory.createTcpSlave(false);
    slave.addProcessImage(getModscanProcessImage(1));

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                slave.start();
            } catch (ModbusInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    while (true) {
        synchronized (slave) {
            try {
                slave.wait(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (ProcessImage processImage : slave.getProcessImages()) {
            try {
                updateProcessImage((BasicProcessImage) processImage);
            } catch (IllegalDataAddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

static void updateProcessImage(BasicProcessImage processImage) throws IllegalDataAddressException {

    int hr16Value = processImage.getNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 16, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED).intValue();
    if (hr16Value != twoByteIntUnsignedSwapped) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test failed on TWO_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED. Expected " + twoByteIntUnsignedSwapped + " but was: " + hr16Value);
    }

    short hr17Value = processImage.getNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 17, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED).shortValue();
    if (hr17Value != twoByteIntSignedSwapped) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test failed on TWO_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED. Expected " + twoByteIntSignedSwapped + " but was: " + hr17Value);
    }

    long hr18Value = processImage.getNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 18, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED).longValue();
    if (hr18Value != fourByteIntUnsignedSwappedSwapped) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test failed on FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_INVERTED. Expected " + fourByteIntUnsignedSwappedSwapped + "  but was: " + hr18Value);
    }

    int hr20Value = processImage.getNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 20, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED).intValue();
    if (hr20Value != fourByteIntSignedSwappedSwapped) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test failed on FOUR_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED_INVERTED. Expected  " + fourByteIntSignedSwappedSwapped + "  but was: " + hr20Value);
    }

    long hr22Value = processImage.getNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 22, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED).longValue();
    if (hr22Value != register22) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test failed on FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_INVERTED. Expected " + register22 + " but was: " + hr22Value);
    }

}

static class BasicProcessImageListener implements ProcessImageListener {
    @Override
    public void coilWrite(int offset, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {
        System.out.println("Coil at " + offset + " was set from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void holdingRegisterWrite(int offset, short oldValue, short newValue) {
        // Add a small delay to the processing.
        //            try {
        //                Thread.sleep(500);
        //            }
        //            catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //                // no op
        //            }
        System.out.println("HR at " + offset + " was set from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    }
}

static BasicProcessImage getModscanProcessImage(int slaveId) {
    BasicProcessImage processImage = new BasicProcessImage(slaveId);
    //processImage.setAllowInvalidAddress(true);
    processImage.setInvalidAddressValue(Short.MIN_VALUE);


    //Register 16 Holds 1 and the data is transmitted as 0b00000001 00000000 which is 256
    //processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 16, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED, new Integer(256));
    processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 16, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED, 29187);
    //Registery 16 Holds -2 and the data is transmitted as 0b1111110 11111111 which is -257
    processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 17, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED, -257);

    //Register 18 Holds 1 and the data is transmitted as 0b00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 which is 16777216
    processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 18, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED, 16777216L);

    //Register 20 Holds -2 and the data is transmitted as 0b1111110 11111111 1111111 11111111 which is -16777217
    processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 20, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_SIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED, (long) -16777217);

    //Register 22 Holds 803213 and the data is transmitted as 0b10001101 01000001 00001100 00000000 which is 2369850368
    processImage.setNumeric(RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 22, DataType.FOUR_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED_SWAPPED_SWAPPED, 2369850368L);


    processImage.setExceptionStatus((byte) 151);

    // Add an image listener.
    processImage.addListener(new BasicProcessImageListener());

    return processImage;
}
}
```

**Slave codes for Wemos D1 (device) C language and Arduino IDE:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


const char* ssid = "YOUR-WIFI-NAME";
const char* password = "YOUR-PASS";
int ModbusTCP_port = 502;
 
//////// Required for Modbus TCP / IP /// Requerido para Modbus TCP/IP /////////
#define maxInputRegister 20
#define maxHoldingRegister 20
 
#define MB_FC_NONE 0
#define MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS 3 //implemented
#define MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER 6 //implemented
#define MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS 16 //implemented
//
// MODBUS Error Codes
//
#define MB_EC_NONE 0
#define MB_EC_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION 1
#define MB_EC_ILLEGAL_DATA_ADDRESS 2
#define MB_EC_ILLEGAL_DATA_VALUE 3
#define MB_EC_SLAVE_DEVICE_FAILURE 4
//
// MODBUS MBAP offsets
//
#define MB_TCP_TID 0
#define MB_TCP_PID 2
#define MB_TCP_LEN 4
#define MB_TCP_UID 6
#define MB_TCP_FUNC 7
#define MB_TCP_REGISTER_START 8
#define MB_TCP_REGISTER_NUMBER 10
 
byte ByteArray[260];
unsigned int MBHoldingRegister[maxHoldingRegister];
 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



WiFiServer MBServer(ModbusTCP_port);



void setup() {
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(".");
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { delay(500); Serial.print("."); }

  MBServer.begin();
  Serial.println("Connected ");
  Serial.print("ESP8266 Slave Modbus TCP/IP ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP()); Serial.print(":"); Serial.println(String(ModbusTCP_port));
  Serial.println("Modbus TCP/IP Online");
}
 
 
void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected // Modbus TCP/IP
  WiFiClient client = MBServer.available();
  if (!client) { return; }

  boolean flagClientConnected = 0;
  byte byteFN = MB_FC_NONE;
  int Start;
  int WordDataLength;
  int ByteDataLength;
  int MessageLength;
 
  // Modbus TCP/IP
  while (client.connected()) {
    if(client.available()) {
      flagClientConnected = 1;
      int i = 0;
      while(client.available()) {
    ByteArray[i] = client.read();
    i++;
  }
  client.flush();

  ///// code here --- codigo aqui

  ///////// Holding Register [0] A [9] = 10 Holding Registers Escritura
  ///////// Holding Register [0] A [9] = 10 Holding Registers Writing

  MBHoldingRegister[0] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[1] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[2] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[3] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[4] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[5] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[6] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[7] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[8] = random(0,12);
  MBHoldingRegister[9] = random(0,12);

  ///////// Holding Register [10] A [19] = 10 Holding Registers Lectura
  ///// Holding Register [10] A [19] = 10 Holding Registers Reading

  int Temporal[10];

  Temporal[0] = MBHoldingRegister[10];
  Temporal[1] = MBHoldingRegister[11];
  Temporal[2] = MBHoldingRegister[12];
  Temporal[3] = MBHoldingRegister[13];
  Temporal[4] = MBHoldingRegister[14];
  Temporal[5] = MBHoldingRegister[15];
  Temporal[6] = MBHoldingRegister[16];
  Temporal[7] = MBHoldingRegister[17];
  Temporal[8] = MBHoldingRegister[18];
  Temporal[9] = MBHoldingRegister[19];

  /// Enable Output 14
  digitalWrite(14, MBHoldingRegister[14] );

  //// debug
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Serial.print("[");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("] ");
    Serial.print(Temporal[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("");

  //// end code - fin 


  //// routine Modbus TCP
  byteFN = ByteArray[MB_TCP_FUNC];
  Start = word(ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_START],ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_START+1]);
  WordDataLength = word(ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_NUMBER],ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_NUMBER+1]);
}

// Handle request
switch(byteFN) {

  case MB_FC_NONE:
    break;

  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS: // 03 Read Holding Registers
    ByteDataLength = WordDataLength * 2;
    ByteArray[5] = ByteDataLength + 3; //Number of bytes after this one.
    ByteArray[8] = ByteDataLength; //Number of bytes after this one (or number of bytes of data).
    for(int i = 0; i < WordDataLength; i++) {
      ByteArray[ 9 + i * 2] = highByte(MBHoldingRegister[Start + i]);
      ByteArray[10 + i * 2] = lowByte(MBHoldingRegister[Start + i]);
    }
    MessageLength = ByteDataLength + 9;
    client.write((const uint8_t *)ByteArray,MessageLength);
    byteFN = MB_FC_NONE;
    break;

  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER: // 06 Write Holding Register
    MBHoldingRegister[Start] = word(ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_NUMBER],ByteArray[MB_TCP_REGISTER_NUMBER+1]);
    ByteArray[5] = 6; //Number of bytes after this one.
    MessageLength = 12;
    client.write((const uint8_t *)ByteArray,MessageLength);
    byteFN = MB_FC_NONE;
    break;

  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS: //16 Write Holding Registers
    ByteDataLength = WordDataLength * 2;
    ByteArray[5] = ByteDataLength + 3; //Number of bytes after this one.
    for(int i = 0; i < WordDataLength; i++) {
      MBHoldingRegister[Start + i] = word(ByteArray[ 13 + i * 2],ByteArray[14 + i * 2]);
    }
    MessageLength = 12;
    client.write((const uint8_t *)ByteArray,MessageLength); 
    byteFN = MB_FC_NONE;
    break;
}
  }
}
```

**Client Code in python with pyModbusTCP:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
 
client = ModbusClient(host="192.168.1.105", port=502, auto_open=True, auto_close=True, timeout=10)
data2 = client.write_single_register(14, 1) # FUNCTIE 06 - (Write register) (register=14, data=1)
data = client.read_holding_registers(14, 1) # FUNCTIE 03 - Read register (enkele register) (register=14, length=1)
print ("Data register: ", data[0])
client.close()
```

[Modbus Protocol Specification](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf)